# Transform an observable to array in order to draw googlechart

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2, google-visualization, rxjs6

I use angular cli 6 and angularfire2. My code works very well to display the data in the template with a classic ngfor loop and an asynchronous pipe. But I also have to use the data for a Google graph. This one needs data from the typescript. How can I convert my observable into an array in the typescript as described below?

I can use a plunker if you need it

I have in my firedatabase :

```
--ppss
  --pps1key
    --treatement : value1
    --DateA : DateA1
    --Date B : DateB1
  --pps2key
    --treatement : value2
    --DateA : DateA2
    --Date B : DateB2
```

I want display data in my //component.ts like this :

```
 this.data1 = [
 ['treatement','dateA', 'dateB'],
 [ 'Treatement.value1',  new DateA1(), new DateB1()],
 [ 'Treatement.value2',  new DateA2(), new DateB2()]
 ];
```

From my service, i send an observable like that :

```
getPPSByPatientid(Patientid: string)
{
return this.database.list('/ppss', ref => 
ref.orderByChild("Patientid").equalTo(Patientid)).valueChanges();
}
```

I try this but i have many error :

```
patientid: string;
ppssToDisplay;
data1: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
      this.patientid = urlParameters['id'];});
      this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getPPSByPatientid(this.patientid);

let interestingFields = [ 'treatement','dateA', 'dateB'];
this.ppssToDisplay.subscribe(obj => {
  this.data1 = [
    interestingFields,
    interestingFields.map(field => obj[field]),
  ];
console.log(this.data1);
});
```

Error:

```
core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Not an array Error: Not an array
```

Comment: Show the messages or errors you get.

Comment: @jdv   core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Not an array
Error: Not an array

Comment: @jdv the second part of array is undefined...

Comment: Always [edit] the question to update it with requested information. I've done this for you this time.

Comment: ok thank you i will do this next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `.subscribe` to get the data out of the Observable:

```
this.ppssToDisplay.subscribe(obj => {
  this.data1 = [
    interestingFields,
    interestingFields.map(field => obj[field]),
  ];
});
```

Depending upon how `data1` is used, you may also be able to use Angular's `async` pipe in the template instead of calling `.subscribe` directly: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: I juste need To define data1 in typescript and googlechart made the rest. But i have this error : SUBSCRIB doesn't exist on type any[]

Comment: Mange it is aborder way to define data1? Thx docteur

Comment: What does `valueChanges` return? I thought it was an Observable

Comment: Ok i go To see that and i comeback

Comment: @ Explosion Pils When i use your solution i have this error :   RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Not an array
Error: Not an array

Comment: I think the probleme is in " interestingFields.map(field => obj[field])," because it send me undefined array